# Teleportation Coordinates Question

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I make a teleporter that doesn't need a pressure plate to activate?

In other words I would like to execute a command which is executed when one steps in a certain location. For example, a command that would test if someone is somewhere and then teleport them somewhere else.

I have a few ideas, but I do not know how I know to complete the assignment.
Maybe these commands?

```
/execute <playername> ~ ~ ~ /tp <playername> ~ ~ ~
/execute <playername> ~ ~ ~ /fill ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ minecraft:redstone
```

Comment: When will it activate? Randomly? By time? When user is somewhere? When user throws an item?

Comment: You can create a teleport without pressure plates by teleporting only people within a certain radius. (Say 2 blocks if its under the floor.) You can have this set to every player, every entity, or a specific player / entity.

Comment: How do we vote to re-open this question. I understand whst the user means and left an edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I generate a redstone signal when players are near?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41650/how-can-i-generate-a-redstone-signal-when-players-are-near)

Answer (score 1):

The `/execute` command only needs to be used when the command sender or origin of execution needs to change, which is not the case here.

The selector parameters `x`, `y`, and `z` for coordinates, and `r` for radius, will be included in the selector for `/tp`. For example, the following teleports players who are within 1 block of (10, 64, 10) to (15, 64, 15).

```
/tp @a[x=10,y=64,z=10,r=1] 15 64 15
```

Answer (score 0):

`/execute (playername) (x) (y) (z) /tp (playername) (x) (y) (z)` (as you said) should work just fine! That is the easy way; you could use the other one you said too, just hook it up to a redstone mechanism where the redstone placed by the `/fill` command is next to a redstone block which will activate the redstone, and have a command block containing just the `/tp` command being powered upon the redstone being placed.

If you want this to be a one-time thing, then don't worry about this, but if you want this to be reused then add an extra command block being powered the redstone filling the redstone to air (preferably before a repeater; make this command block powered after the `/tp` one) so it can be placed again upon the same player walking in that spot.

I recommend the `/execute (playername) (x) (y) (z) /tp (playername) (x) (y) (z)` one as it is much easier and only uses one command (depended on the clock to keep it running; if you use a `/setblock` or `/fill` clock it is a minimum of three command blocks.

Bear in mind you don't have to do a certain player; instead of `/execute (playername)...` you can have `@p` (nearest player to the command block; useful if you place the command block close to the position where the player needs to be), `@a` (useful if you want all the players in the world/on the server to be teleported to the same place) or `@e` (useful if you want it to be able to be activated by entities (e.g. Items, minecarts or mobs).

You can also make it even more specific when using `@e`! Add some tags after it to change the name of the entity needed, the type of entity needed and so much more!

`/execute @e[type=Zombie,name=Bob] (x) (y) (z) /tp @e[type=Zombie,name=Bob] (x) (y) (z)`

With that command, say you had more than one zombie named Bob. If one walked in those coordinates, all zombie Bobs would be teleported. If you only want the one that stepped in the position to be teleported, put the command block one block underneath the position and do this:

`/execute @e[type=Zombie,name=Bob] (x) (y) (z) /tp @e[type=Zombie,name=Bob,range=3]`

Of course, this won't work when more than one of the Bobs are within three blocks of the command block, but the command can be changed accordingly.

Hope this helps!